# Strapi + MongoDB not saving password field

Tags: strapi

I am trying to save a password in password type field in Strapi with MongoDB, but is always empty. I am testing through API calls using Insomnia software. The endpoints are already enable in Strapi configuration and the data is stored, just password is missing. For example, doing a POST API call with this data:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "Password": "testpassword",
    "email": "testmail@hotmail.com"
}
```

It is stored this way:

```
{
  "_id": "6097eadeb01bb600159d9319",
  "name": "Test",
  "email": "testmail@hotmail.com",
  "published_at": "2021-05-09T13:59:58.204Z",
  "createdAt": "2021-05-09T13:59:58.211Z",
  "updatedAt": "2021-05-09T13:59:58.211Z",
  "__v": 0,
  "id": "6097eadeb01bb600159d9319"
}
```

If I enter to Strapi and check the created user, the password field is missing too, and even if I enter it manually, it is not saved either.

Answer (score 0):

The password field is not displayed on the admin panel for security reasons. but u can update it from the admin panel. you will have to over write the create function without using the sanitize(which removes the password from the response) in order to get the password in response.